# Tools for simulating a tiny Universe

Tags: math, simulation, physics

I want to know what programming language or tool I can use to simulate a small universe? I want to define rules, parameters and patterns. For example, define an atom with all its properties and then see how everything works and moves.

I know this is a strange question, but I have researched and I have not found much about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Processing](https://processing.org/) a java framework, it is great for running simulations.

This [is a book "The Nature of Code"](http://natureofcode.com/) that is about simulating natural systems in processing, the book is free online, and the author creates a lot of great video tutorials for processing also.

[Here](https://github.com/PatrickMurphy/ProcessingSketches/blob/master/genetics/genetics.pde) is one of my processing sketches that is a very simple genetics simulation.

Processing has some libraries that do a lot of physics for you also! I think they are mostly wrappers for box2d and some particle systems.

Comment: sounds interesting!